# iOS:Which Augmented Reality SDK for virtual try room to be used?

Tags: ios, opencv, augmented-reality

I am working on `iOS` `Augmented Reality` project, Where i need to integrate virtual dressing concept.
I tried `OpenCV`, it worked as desired for me in Face Detection Scenario Only
 but when i  did Upper Body Portion, That didn't work for me as desired. 
I used `UPPER_BODY_HAAR_CASCADE` but it didn't work as it was desired

it came as something like

[image: Current Image Result]

but my desired output is something like this

[image: Required Output]

If someone has achieved this functionality in `iOS`, Please Reply me

Comment: Get the head and the body frames and subtract them

Comment: it is supposed to go to the bottom even i remove this.. upper to waist like shirt..

Comment: Hi @magid I would like to create an application with the same concept using watches and jewellery, Kindly watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBE11ROpxHE   and guide me the way to achieve the concept. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answer you are looking for. You make your app depending on the sdk you choose. Most of them are quite expensive to use and may suffer from changing the use policy. Additionally you drag all the extensive functionality you don't need into your app. So at the end of day your app is 60-100MB in size.

If I was you (and I was in similar situation), I would develop own little sdk with the functionality you need. If you know how to do it then it takes couple days for the basic things to work. Plus opencv and you are in good shape.

PS. @Tommy asked interesting question. How one can approach to implement something like on this video: youtube.com/watch?v=IBE11ROpxHE

Adding some info which is too long for comment.

@Tommy Nice video. It seems to have all we need to proceed. First of all, for any AR application you need your camera (mobile phone camera) calibration info. In simple case, it contains two matrixes: camera matrix and distortion matrix. Camera matrix is then used for creating opengl projection matrix (how the 3d model is projected to 2d flat screen, field of view, planes, etc). And distortions matrix is used for example, for warping parts of your input frame in case of detecting something. In the example with watches, we need to detect the belt and watches body in order to place the 3d model in that position. Given the paper watches is not having ideal perspective with 90 degrees angle to the eye, it needs to be transformed to this view.

In other words, your paper watches looks like this:

```
  /---/
 /   /
/---/
```

And for the analysis and detecting the model name you need it look like this:

```
 ---
|   |
|   |
 ---
```

This is where distortion matrix is used in order to have precise transformation. And different cameras have their own distortions.

Most of application use so called offline calibration. There is a chessboard and its feed into opencv functions that detect cells on series of frames with different perspective, and build the matrices based on how the cells are shaped.

In your case, the belt of your watch may be designed in a way that it will contain all the needed for *online* calibration. On your video it has special pattern, I'm pretty sure its done exactly for this purpose. You may do the same and use chessboard pattern for simplicity.

Then you could use lets say 25 first frames for online calibration and then having all the matrixes you go for detecting paper watches, building projection matrix and replace it with your 3d model. If all is done right then your paper watcthes will have coord 0 0 0 in 3d space and you could easily place something else in that position.

Comment: Ok, I got it, can you provide me some links where to follow..? Or Some Specific, as you are saying is to broad..

Comment: There are couple of example projects that show how to approach the basic AR functionality: (a) video capture + opengl frames drawing as a texture and (b) device calibration that allows to generate projection matrix that is in line with your device lens and other camera HW specs and this all makes it possible to perform normal opengl drawing on top of your video frame textures and (c) adding opencv support to your project and using it for things you need.

Comment: Hi @Umka I would like to create an application with the same concept using watches and jewellery, Kindly watch this video youtube.com/watch?v=IBE11ROpxHE and guide me the way to achieve the concept. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share you mail ID ., We will discuss further

Comment: @Umka, I would like to more about those example projects, can you share some links?